# Retrofit v2.0.0-beta2 multipart/form-data file upload - How to dynamically change filename?

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data, multipart, okhttp

I am using the newest Retrofit version avaliable (v2.0.0-beta2) and I have a problem with sending data using Multipart request. [I've already read that there is a bug so that the filename needs to be set manually](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server). I've followed the instructions provided by this tutorial and also on Retrofit's GitHub, so now it works properly. The only problem I have is that I would like to set the filename dynamically, so that each file I upload has a different name. How can I do this?

My code:

ApiRequest.java:

```
public interface ApiRequest {
    @Multipart
    @POST("FileSend")
    Call<ApiResponse> uploadFile(@Part("photo\"; filename=\"receipt.jpg\" ") RequestBody file, @Part("login") RequestBody login);
}
```

Making a request to API:

```
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), bytes);
RequestBody loginBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), login);
ApiRequest apiRequest = ServerImpl.getsInstance().getRetrofit().create(ApiRequest.class);
Call<ApiResponse> sendReceiptCall = apiRequest.uploadFile(fileBody, loginBody);
sendReceiptCall.enqueue(this);
```

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063#issuecomment-145920568

Comment: @EugenPechanec The solution which you had posted actually worked for me. Thanks!